# Getting a login token even though I've already retrieved one

Tags: mediawiki-api

So, what I am trying to do is logging into a mediawiki instance with a bot account.
According to the API, the first step in order to log in is to retrieve a login token.

```
        URL anUrl;
        String s;
        try {
            anUrl = new URL("https://home.blazingumbra.com/wiki/api.php?action=query&format=json&meta=tokens&type=login");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) anUrl.openConnection();
            ReaderMaker maker = new ReaderMaker();
            BufferedReader br = maker.fromInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            s = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        //convert it into pojo.
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        QueryLoginTokenResponse queryLoginTokenResponse = gson.fromJson(s, 
        QueryLoginTokenResponse.class);
```

With this token, I am trying to finally login:
(API requires sending a POST-request)

```
try {
            String loginToken = queryLoginTokenResponse.getToken();
            URL anURL = ECommands.makeURL("https://home.blazingumbra.com/wiki/api.php?action=login&format=json");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) anURL.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text");
            connection.connect();
            String body = "&lgname=bot&lgpassword=secret&lgtoken="+loginToken;

            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.writeBytes(body);

            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            ReaderMaker readerMaker = new ReaderMaker();
            BufferedReader in = readerMaker.fromInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
            StringBuilder stringBuffer = new StringBuilder();
            while((s =in.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(s);
            }
            s = stringBuffer.toString();
        } catch (IOException|NullPointerException e) {
            msg.editMessage("There's a mistake while trying to call the login page.").complete();
            return;
        }
```

Issue is, after trying to login, the response looks like this:

```
{"warnings":{"login":{"*":"Fetching a token via action=login is deprecated. Use action=query&meta=tokens&type=login instead."}},"login":{"result":"NeedToken","token":"b116120f436071e5209a9b0e707e8c045b35d61e+\\"}}
```

[Login-API-Page](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Login)

Since I am kind of stuck here in the deep end, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the response gives you a token, that means you did not send one, the login failed because of that, and the API is assuming you are using the long-deprecated "do a login attempt without a token first, get an error message with a token, repeat login with token" protocol.

If you *are* sending a token, then your session (which the token is validated against) got lost. Typically this is caused by incorrect (or no) cookie handling in the client.

Comment: `If you are sending a token, then your session (which the token is validated against) got lost. Typically this is caused by incorrect (or no) cookie handling in the client.` Which is correct. I discovered that the class ``HttpUrlConnection`` provides no sufficient session handling for this, I now go with ``javax.servlet.HttpClient``. Thanks you for your answer!